# Extra/repeated pronoun after name "Time, it waits...": correct, colloquialism or error?

Tags: pronouns, repetition

Is the pleonastic use of a pronoun after a name correct? Is it used to convey a specific tone to the sentence? Is it used at all by native speakers?

Take for example this verse from the song *Only the good die young* (Iron Maiden), a variation on the (more correct) sentence "Time waits for no man".

> Time, **it** waits for no man

I find myself using this construction quite often, for example in sentences like

> Then we split up: I went shopping for groceries; Mel, Frank and Tina, **they** went to the zoo.

Is this construction Name + Pronoun acceptable, at least in spoken English?

Has this phenomenon a technical name?

Comment: It is definitely used colloquially but I would not use it formally.  It's like a way of emphasizing the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The use of additional pronouns is perfectly acceptable as long as it's understandable.

In your example

> Time, **it** waits for no man.

"***It***" emphasizes the singularity of "***time***" and might be expected since the usual quote is

> Time and tide wait for no man.

However, one would not usually say

> Time and tide ***they*** wait for no man.

Whereas if you were speaking to a friend and wanted to emphasize Susan, you might say

> Well Susan, *(what)* **she** said...

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *perfectly* acceptable in speech - it sounds a bit too highbrow and poetic if you're just saying how your day was. In song lyrics or prose, though, it's definitely acceptable.